# How to install Lubuntu on Aspire one running Ubuntu 10.4

Tags: installation, lubuntu, acer

I have an old aspire one netbook I want to resuscitate. It currently runs Ubuntu 10.4 but tells me to go away if I try the Update function (only wants to do a partial update - Adobe flash-player has an issue)

Decided to kill Ubuntu and load Lubuntu. Easier said than done -I've been trying for about a week of nights now and I am about to through the thing off a cliff!

My issues are: 
No CD drive - has to make bootable flashdisk.
Unetbootin does not run if I download it. (There are some obscure comments about running some script in the terminal window to make it run, but I tried and cannot figure it out)
Tried making a bootable flasdisk with startup disk creator, but this just hangs if I try to boot from it.
Millions of pages of how-to's but most dating back many years, so relevance is unknown 
New to Linux and not enjoying the experience.

Seems like running Ubuntu is like building your own race car -  it can go like stink, but only if you know what you do. Think I want a good old simple Toyota!

Comment: Actually if you download Unetbootin from their site you do *need to run it from the terminal* you can *also* install it from the repositories (I'm not 100% sure if it's in the Lucid repositories though), or search for the PPA and download the deb package.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably forgotten to make the unetbootin file executable.

Right click on unetbootin-linux-xxx, click on Properties, choose the tab Permissions. Check the small square Allow executing file as program.

Now double click unetbootin-linux-xxx and fill in your password.

You can also do it through the command line. Open a Terminal with Ctrl + Alt + T and type:

`cd /path/to/unetbootin`

`chmod +x unetbootin-linux-xxx`

`./unetbootin-linux-xxx`

Finally, fill in your password and create a bootable usb.

xxx=versionnumber

Having done this make sure your laptop boots first from usb in bios.

Furthermore if the regular installation image does not work you might consider using the alternate installation image, downloadable from here:

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/13.04/release/

This image lets you install Lubuntu via commandline, which is less taxing on your system and still easy to do. All you'll have to do is answer a few installation questions.